# Do I have to use an IV when using GPG with AES 256?

Tags: aes, gnupg

Do I have to use an IV when using GPG with AES 256?  Or does GPG handle that for me?

I've noticed that I get different results each time I run the encryption, i.e.

```
gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --armor test
```

But is this secure enough without an IV?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to refer you to [Thomas Pornin's answer to Will encrypting the same file with GPG and the same key produce the same ciphertext?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33754), which is (as usual) really excellent.

It boils down to: Yes, there is a random IV and an additional random salt during the password to key transformation.

The relevant paragraph is:

> The third point also applies when doing password-based encryption (encryption is done with a password, not with a recipient's public key). Password-based encryption also adds a fourth randomization, which is the [salt in the password-to-key transform, 3.7.1.3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt).

Section number added by me from his quotation, link updated.

The third point is:

> - When doing the symmetric encryption itself, a random IV is used, and will be different (with overwhelming probability) for each invocation. See [section 5.7](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt) for details.

Link updated again.